# Как сделать повторный запуск функции после выполнения ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть функция, которая проверяет наличие в поле формы символа т.е. если символ или символы присутствуют, тогда присвоить класс valid иначе удалить данный класс

Как сделать повторный запуск данной функции после выполнения ajax запроса?

```js
$('.form_Input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim().length) {
    $(this).addClass('valid');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('valid');
  }
});
```

```css
.valid{background:#3f9;}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="address_email" value="" class="form_Input" placeholder="E-Mail" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

У jquery ajax  есть методы:

- success - Функция, которая будет вызвана в случае успешного завершения запроса. (с версии 3.0 используется done)
- complete - Функция, которая будет вызвана после завершения ajax запроса (срабатывает после функций-обработчиков success и error)
- always (jquery >= 1.6) - Функция, которая будет вызвана в любом случае - при успехе и при ошибке, не важно.

Выбирайте на своё усмотрение

---

Триггернуть функицю: `$('.form_Input').trigger('change');`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Подскажет, пожалуйста правильно ли я понял про функцию `complete` `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { мой код });`

Comment: @Alexandr не совсем. я скорее имел в виду это: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос -  смотрим пример начинающийся с `$.ajax({`  ..... или тут  https://snipp.ru/jquery/ajax-jquery

Comment: Триггернуть функицю: `$('.form_Input').trigger('change');` можно, пожалуйста на моём примере показать как это будет выглядеть